# How can I know the number of inserted characters by Document.insertString() method?

Tags: java, swing, defaultstyleddocument

I am making my custom implementation of DefaultStyledDocument. And sometimes, I need to know how many characters will be (or has been) inserted by the Document.insertString() method.

But I did not find how to compute it. (The method insertString() itself can't help me as it returns void).

So is it possible to compute this value ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the length() method? i.e.:

```
String s = "Example";     
int len = s.length();
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, my question is not so accurate. I wondered, because of the uses of Styles.

Comment: No problem. Keep on coding :)

Comment: Yes :) Programming is so fun :)